# Transferring GoDaddy domain to AWS Route53 issue,

Tags: godaddy, domain-transfer

I would like to find out if it is possible to transfer the domain bought from GoDaddy to AWS Route 53 when the domain name is not included in the list of supported TLD in Route 53?

e.g.

GoDaddy `XXX.Sydney` to AWS Route 53 - does not have `.Sydney` domain name.

How do I transfer in this case?

Comment: You don't have to transfer the domain to let Route 53 serve your DNS records.  You could leave it registered at Godaddy and assign the NameServers at Godaddy to be the ones that Route 53 wants.

Answer (score 2):

From [Transferring a Domain to Amazon Route 53](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/domain-transfer-to-route-53.html#domain-transfer-to-route-53-proc):

> To transfer a domain to Amazon Route 53 from another registrar
>
> 1. Confirm that Amazon Route 53 supports the top-level domain (for example, .com or .org) for the domain name that you want to transfer. For more information, see [Domains that You Can Register with Amazon Route 53](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/registrar-tld-list.html). **If your top-level domain isn't on the list, you can't currently transfer the domain name to Amazon Route 53**.

It seems that `.sydney` is not on [the above list of TLDs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/registrar-tld-list.html#S) so cannot be transferred at the current time.

Answer (score 0):

If your domain is not in the list of supported top level domain you can't transfer it. The reason being AWS has to communicate with TLD do that transfer. If your domain is supported, the detail steps to transfer the domain is given at
https://cloudopian.com/blog/how-to-transfer-domain-registrar-from-godaddy-to-amazon-route-53/

List of support domains are given at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/registrar-tld-list.html